# Getting error while creating BPEL Project in Eclipse

Tags: wso2, eclipse-juno, bpel

I am trying to create a simple BPEL HelloWorld project in eclipse. But when i create a project i get error in my HelloWorldArtifact.wsdl as:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'plnk:partnerLinkType'. One of '{"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":import, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":types, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":message, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":portType, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":binding, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/":service}' is expected.    helloworldArtifacts.wsdl    /HelloWorld/bpelContent
```

at:

```
 <plnk:partnerLinkType name="helloworld">
        <plnk:role name="helloworldProvider" portType="tns:helloworld"/>
    </plnk:partnerLinkType>
```

I am using eclipse Juno 4.2. What is the problem i am unable to get. Looking forward to your replies. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the devStudio version you are using with eclipse?

Comment: I tried it out it seems that the sample project that is generated works fine for me. Did you do any changes or does that error come in the generated code?

Comment: I have downloaded the latest version of eclipse+developerStudio and its working for me. :)